# How can I pass struct as function parameter with ABIEncoderV2 from outside?

Tags: web3js, metamask, struct, abi

have this code:

```
struct UserScore {
    address user;
    uint score;
    uint time;
}
function getWithStruct(UserScore _user) public view returns (address, uint, uint) {
    return (_user.user, _user.score, _user.time);
}
```

It seems that metamask does not support this feature at the moment. But is there a workaround? It is necessary for me that users with metamask could transfer the signed data in the form of structure. What I can do for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can archive this simply by using mapping and return from struct mapping values
>   like this no need of ABIEncoderV2 :

code:

```
struct UserScore {
    address user;
    uint score;
    uint time;
}
mapping(address=>UserScore) public userscore;

function addUserScore(address _user, uint _score, uint _time)public returns (bool success){
    userscore[msg.sender] = UserScore(_user,_score,_time);
    return true;
}
function getWithStruct(address _userAdress) public view returns (address, uint, uint) {
    return (userscore[_userAdress].user, userscore[_userAdress].score, userscore[_userAdress].time);
}
```

Hope this will help you.